# RTK Query reset

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a MUI dialog component that triggers a useLazyQuery action on save to fetch data.
Then on success dispatches another action
My problem is, that after success, I want to reset the state of the useLazyQuery hook in the dialog component, because after success/fail the state is "stuck" like this in the component.
I am confused how should I approach this...
Dismount and mount the dialog component works but it removes the fadeout animation and also unsubscribe the query endpoint.
Is there a best practice here that I am missing?
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, instead of a `lazyQuery` I'd probably just use a normal query hook with a `setState`. That way you can just `skip` it.

```js
const [arg, setArg] = useState(null)
const result = useMyQuery(arg, { skip: arg == null })
```

And then `setArg(null)` to "reset" the thing.

Comment: I think you need to pass skip true for waiting for fetch...
So you say:
1. First set skip to true to wait for fetch
2. onClick set skip to false so the hook will fetch
3. Set skip to true again  
?  
wont the result will still stay the same?

Comment: It will set `skip` to `true` as long as your `arg` is `null` - no query will be made.
When you want a query with an argument to happen, you set `arg`. Then it won't skip, but make the query. If you don't want to have the result around any more, you set `arg` to `null`. It will go back to `uninitialized`.

Comment: yes that works! the previous result is still there though,

Comment: Hey @nadiTime  you said: "I want to reset the state of the useLazyQuery hook in the dialog component, because after success/fail the state is "stuck" like this in the component." but then you said "the previous result is still there though". So, did it solve your problem ?  Based on your comments, the returned "data" still there after you set "null" as I understood.

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up using RTKQuery without hooks. I created a custom hook and inside used `initiate` and `select` with `useSelector` and `dispatch`, than I can reset `someId` when `isSuccess` is `true`.

```
dispatch(api.endpoints.getData.initiate(someId));
const {data, isError, isLoading} = useSelector(state => api.endpoints.getData.select(someId)(state))
```